# Iterate through a list of strings and return a list of strings with only alpha characters

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of words (ex. `word_list = ['python', 'learn', 'regular', '$test', '536ave']`) and I would like to either delete from the list or insert into a new list so that I am left with strings that contain only letters from the alphabet. `(ex. print(clean_list)` that returns['python', 'learn', 'regular']) I thought a regular expression word work such as a variation of ( `clean_list = for word in word_list: re.findall(r'\w+', word)` ) . Seems easy but I am not able to figure it out and I have tried many functions, loops, etc.

Comment: There's a missing bit of punctuation in the second element of your example word list, I would edit it myself, but edits must be at least six characters.

Comment: @OliverTooEh: ...removing "(Beginner)" should be a good edit. There is plenty more to improve. As long as you do not have 2K of rep, make sure to make every edit count so you don't waste reviewer's time.

Comment: Thanks @usr2564301, just submitted it.

Comment: @OliverTooEh well editing a closed question doesn't help much either. Your edit probably will not make this question not a duplicate so again, it will pop for reviewers of edits and if approved, then to reopen the question. As said, try to make your edits count, which means when they can really make a question better

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
clean_list = [ x for x in word_list if x.isalpha() ]
```

or

```
clean_list = list(filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(), word_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regular expressions

```
import re
clean_list = [i for i in word_list if re.match('^[a-zA-Z]+$', i)]
```